# Java Date Validator with Time Zone

Tags: java, apache, date

Do we have any API's to validate if a date is valid or not when date is having EDT/EST in it. I have tried with Joda, Java SimpleDateFormat but i am not able to parse the date.

Below is the sample format i am getting "2017/09/25 16:18:15.099 -0400 EDT".

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
sk

Comment: What do you mean by "i am not able to parse the date"?  What goes wrong when you try?  Is there an error message?  And most important of all, where is the code that you wrote to try?

Comment: You have an offset (-0400) *and* a three letter time zone abbreviation (EDT) in your string? Never seen that before. There’s a first time for everything. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try reading the documentation?

From [the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
 z     time-zone name   zone-name     Pacific Standard Time; PST
 x     zone-offset      offset-x      +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
```

> **Zone names**: This outputs the display name of the time-zone ID. If the count of letters is one, two or three, then the short name is
>   output. …
>
> **Offset X and x**: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. … Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a
>   colon, such as '+0130'. …

So let’s try that:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017/09/25 16:18:15.099 -0400 EDT",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS xx zzz", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

This produces a `ZonedDateTime` of `2017-09-25T16:18:15.099-04:00[America/New_York]`.

**Validation**

In the code above `ZonedDateTime` picks up the time zone from your string and ignores the offset. To validate that the two agree, we can parse the same string both into a `ZonedDateTime` and into an `OffsetDateTime` and compare. The latter picks up the offset and ignores the time zone abbreviation, so this will work:

```
    String inputDateTimeWithZone = "2017/09/25 16:18:15.099 -0400 EDT";
    DateTimeFormatter formatterWithOffsetAndZone 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS xx zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(inputDateTimeWithZone,
            formatterWithOffsetAndZone);
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputDateTimeWithZone, 
            formatterWithOffsetAndZone);
    if (! zdt.toOffsetDateTime().equals(odt)) {
        System.err.println("Offset does not match: is " + odt.getOffset()
                + ", but time zone " + zdt.getZone() + " implies offset " + zdt.getOffset());
    }
```

**Avoid the three letter time zone abbreviations where you can**

EST and EDT may also be used about Australian Eastern Standard and Daylight Time, respectively. Three letter time zone abbreviations are not standardized and are often ambiguous. It would be safer if you either could get a string with a time zone ID in the *region/city* format (like America/New_York) or you simply stripped off the abbreviation and relied on the offset alone, since this is unambiguous.

**The modern Java date and time API**

Today I recommend `java.time`, AKA JSR-310, over Joda-Time and certainly over the long outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. To me it’s proven very nice to work with, and it certainly doesn’t come with the surprises of the old classes. It’s built-in with Java 8 and later. If using Java 6 or 7, you may be tempted to consider Joda-Time at first, but if you’re ready to accept an external dependency, why not take [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7?